Thunderbird Not Downloading Older Emails
I'm looking to get all of my email from a few email accounts (yahoo, gmail and AOL) from the beginning of those accounts.  My new instance of Thunderbird on my laptop only downloads approx 3 years of email.
Is there a way to get the entire account downloaded irrespective of date?
Thanks.

Check your settings  on the Sychronization & Storage page.

Thanks.  "Synchronize all messages locally regardless of age" is checked.  Would it help to change it to "synchronize the most recent 20 years"?


Is there enough storage space for all files? 2. Does increasing the Cache size help? 3. Does clicking Get Messages while a mailbox is selected (e.g., GMail Inbox) help? 4. Is download taking place, but slowed while T'Bird compacts and indexes the database? If so, stop indexing and uncheck Compact all folders...


Thanks.  1. Plenty of space. 2. Overrode auto cache management and put it to 1GB.  3. Maybe, but it's all over the place. 4. did that thanks.     I'm not too comfortable that I'm getting everything so I may just buy something like the systools account downloader tool to make sure.
